# Using colorbox on an ajax file

Tags: php, colorbox

I have a page called `example1.php` . This page calls another page with some
values using ajax that page is `ajax.php`.
Now problem is in ajax.php there is a submit button for which i want to use
colorbox. Now this ajax.php file does not have any header or .js files for
colorbox (all the .js files: colorbox.js and css files: colorobx.css are in the header.php).
So basically i can not add another header to ajax.php as it adds second header to example1.php.
What is the best way to achieve colorbox on ajax.php without adding header?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "`example1.php` calls `ajax.php`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply include the .js and .css files in ajax.php without header, using:

```
<link href="your_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_javascript.js"></script>
```